# Error when deploying backend code to render

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, render

I am relatively new to this field and recently made a project that uses Puppeteer to scrape information based on user inputs. I made the backend with express and the database I used was mongoDB.

The project works fine on my local system and now I want to deploy it on render. I have followed the steps according to their docs, however during the deployment process I end up with an error as follows :

```
Jun 21 08:41:55 AM  > puppeteer@20.6.0 postinstall /opt/render/project/src/backend/node_modules/puppeteer
Jun 21 08:41:55 AM  > node install.js
Jun 21 08:41:55 AM  
Jun 21 08:41:55 AM  Browser download failed /opt/render/project/src/backend/node_modules/@puppeteer/browsers/lib/cjs/launch.js:48
Jun 21 08:41:55 AM      options.platform ??= (0, detectPlatform_js_1.detectBrowserPlatform)();
Jun 21 08:41:55 AM                       ^^^
Jun 21 08:41:55 AM  
Jun 21 08:41:55 AM  SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='
Jun 21 08:41:55 AM      at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:984:16)
Jun 21 08:41:55 AM      at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1032:27)
Jun 21 08:41:55 AM      at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
Jun 21 08:41:55 AM      at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)
Jun 21 08:41:55 AM      at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)
Jun 21 08:41:55 AM      at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:19)
Jun 21 08:41:55 AM      at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
Jun 21 08:41:55 AM      at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/render/project/src/backend/node_modules/@puppeteer/browsers/lib/cjs/main.js:19:19)
Jun 21 08:41:55 AM      at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068:30)
Jun 21 08:41:55 AM      at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
Jun 21 08:41:55 AM  added 14 packages from 10 contributors, removed 29 packages, updated 265 packages and audited 280 packages in 36.049s
```

I tried to change the `??=` to `||` as I searched for that error on google yet it has no effect. I would greatly appreciate any help. Thanks !!

Comment: Whatever Node version you're using does not support the `??=` operator. Time to update, you need [at least v15.0.0](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment#browser_compatibility)

Answer (score 1):

"??=" only support node.js version >=15.14.0  so, When deploying a Node.js project using Render, you can specify the version using the .nvmrc

create .nvmrc in your project, add 15.14.0 in your .nvmrc

```
15.14.0
```

and you can check this link for more information: https://render.com/docs/node-version